# Excel: Using median and if in an array formula gives different result than hand picked cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm calculating the MEDIAN of values in column B, IF the animal in the corresponding row in column A is either cow, pig or fish.

[image: Snip of Excel file (I'm not allowed to post pics yet)].

As you can see, all cows have value 1, two pigs have value 10, one fish has value 100, and some cells have no value. Those values are chosen to calculate easily.

For the MEDIANs I'm expecting:

cow: 1 (3 cows have value 1)

pig: 10 (2 pigs have value 10)

fish: 100 (1 fish has value 100)

I'm using the array formula:

```
{=MEDIAN(IF(A1:A9=D2,B1:B9))}
```

Another option is to by hand put in the cells to calculate, but I don't want to because my real dataset is much bigger and changes all the time:

```
=MEDIAN(B1,B4,B7)
```

The array formula works great, as long as there is more than 1 value in column B for that category. Now my problem is that sometimes I have only one value (category C for instance). The result is than not as expected, but:

fish: 0 (But: 1 fish has value 100!?)

What's going on and how to solve?

Comment: There are million ways to solve this perhaps, but the array formula is elegant and is so close to working!

Comment: Huh. [Documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/median-function-d0916313-4753-414c-8537-ce85bdd967d2) says *"If an array or reference argument contains text, logical values, or empty cells, those values are ignored; however, cells with the value zero are included."* - however, it looks like blanks *are* being interpreted as zeroes when being used in an array... I might be looking at this wrong, but I'm gonna say this is a bug.

Comment: instead of `A1:A9=D2` in the if do: `(A1:A9=D2)*(B1:B9<>"")`

Comment: Hi Scott, that works!

Comment: @dwirony. I actually think the jist is in the array formula, in that it will return the blank cells on row 6 and 9 as a zero. If I have cells with 1, 2, 3, 40, 50 and use '=MEDIAN(A1:A5)' just like that I get 3. If I delete the 3 and the cell is empty I get 21 (average if middle 2 values). If I use the array formula again on the series with the empty cell I get 2. Which is correct of the value 0 was in there. The array formula returned the empty cell as value zero and now it took the median of 0, 1, 2, 40, 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scott gave a working suggestion, which is elegant and thus what I'm looking for. Solution is to exclude empty cells.

Instead of `A1:A9=D2` in the IF do: `(A1:A9=D2)*(B1:B9<>"")`

So full formula became: `{=MEDIAN(IF((A1:A9=F2)*(B1:B9<>""),B1:B9))}`